# using $(this) properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    $(".gear_listing").hover(function(){

            $(".overlay_gears").show();
        },function(){
   $(".overlay_gears").hide();
}
    );
```

above is my jquery code,as u can imagine i am trying to show .overlay_gears div when .gear_listing div is hover,the above code works just fine.the problem is i have many number of .gear_listing divs and many number of .overlay_gears div,when i hover on any div called .gear_listing all the  .overlay_gears div is shown which i dont want.i just want to show the .overlay_gears div under that .gear_listing div.i know i have to make use of $(this).i just don't know how.

i tried doing this:

```
    $(".gear_listing").hover(function(){
        var this=$(this);
            this.$(".overlay_gears").show();
        },function(){
   this.$(".overlay_gears").hide();
}
    );
```

its not working

below is my div structure:

```
               <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="gear_listing relative">

                            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"></div>
                            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
                            </div>

                            <img src="images/list_one.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="gear_listing relative">
                            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"></div>
                            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
                            </div>
                            <img src="images/list_two.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="gear_listing relative">
                            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"></div>
                            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
                            </div>
                            <img src="images/list_three.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Comment: this is a reserved word, also there is a convention of naming objects with a $, so you could use var $this = $(this); ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.overlay_gears` is children of `.gear_listing` so use like this

```
$(".gear_listing").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".overlay_gears").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $(this).children(".overlay_gears").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: thank you it works now,but can i do this with some kind of animations?the .overlay_gears div is just popping up,can i give it some fade in or zoomin or someother kind of animations?

Answer (score 5):

Use `.find()` and `.slideToggle()` for animation effects or use `.fadeToggle()`

```
$(".gear_listing").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".overlay_gears").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$(".gear_listing").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".overlay_gears").stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfopaj7e/2/)

Answer (score 2):

> Use `this` as the `second-argument` in selector which is [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

*By default, selectors perform their searches within the `DOM starting at the document root`. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function.*

*Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "SELECTOR", this )` is equivalent to  `$(this).find("SELECTOR")`*

```js
$(".gear_listing").hover(function() {
  $(".overlay_gears", this).show();
}, function() {
  $(".overlay_gears", this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `overlay_gears` is a child element of `gear_listing`,you can use `.find()` method

```
$(".gear_listing").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".overlay_gears").show();
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".overlay_gears").hide();
});
```

Comment: Not sure why people preferred other posts over this:(

Comment: @Rayon the best part is, we both give the answers first. and the bad part is OP didn't even check our answers I think.  :D

Comment: Not sure what was wrong with our posts.. Tried hard to make guesses.. Amazing :(

Comment: You got the luck to have atleast 2 upvotes. Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you first needs to hide all `.overlay_gears` on hover and just needs to show the particular `.overlay_gears` that is the child of current hovered parent. And then in 'unhover' event you can simply hide all `.overlay_gears` divs..

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="gear_listing relative">

            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"> overlay_gears data1 overlay_gears data1</div>
            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="gear_listing relative">
            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"> overlay_gears data2 overlay_gears data2</div>
            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="gear_listing relative">
            <div class="overlay_gears absolute"> overlay_gears data3 overlay_gears data3 overlay_gears data3</div>
            <div class="gear_description absolute">
                <span>afdfdsfds sfd</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".gear_listing" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( ".overlay_gears" ).hide();
        $( ".overlay_gears", this ).show();
      }, function() {
        $( ".overlay_gears" ).hide();
      }
    );
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfopaj7e/

> I have just removed `<img>` tag for testing purpose and added few css in Fiddle for the visual thingy

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(".gear_listing").hover(function(){ 
$(this).children('.overlay_gears').show();
}
```

here we select all elements inside $(this) with required class
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_descendants.asp

Answer (score 0):

pass an event in function like

```
function(evt){
var th = $(evt.target);
$(th).find(".overlay_gears").show();
}
```